# Selenium WebDriver Java: not able to select a value from a drop-down list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to select an option from a `drop-down list`, and I'm not able using the common methods of the `Select class`.

I also tried the `selectByVisibleName` and `selectByValue` and same result.

```java
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@model='typeOfCover']")));
oSelect.selectByIndex(2);
```

Here is the piece of HTML of this drop-down list.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a list of web elements. List WebElement
You have more flexibility and its a better practice

Answer (score 2):

Your locator seems wrong.

Try:

```
Select menu = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see any [HTML select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) in the code you provided hence you will not be able to use [Select class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

My expectation is that you need to amend you XPath locator to match the element by `data-original-index` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp), something like:

```
WebElement secondValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-original-index='2']/a"));
secondValue.click();
```

More information on using XPath:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try debugging your code in the IDE.
2. Or try your XPath selector in the Chrome dev tools elements tab, hit `Ctrl + F` and you can test your XPath, CSS, etc. See what that selector is actually finding.

It looks like you do need to click that button first and then select from the UL.

Hope this helps.